# What tool to crimp these connectors

Tags: crimp

Please excuse my inexperience in this matter.

I have purchased some new pick ups for my guitar but it appears the manufacturer of the guitar has opted for a proprietary method of connection rather than simple solder. With that in mind I have to add to the new pick ups I purchased a five pin molex plug and the female pins that sit inside the plug. How do I crimp the female pins to the new pick up wire? I have found crimping videos and am happy with that. It is the required tool I am in search of.

This is the pin I've purchased: http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0500798100_CRIMP_TERMINALS.xml&channel=Products&Lang=en-US

I know there is a special molex tool I can buy that would be much quicker and easier to use but at $300 it's more than I paid for my guitar and it's likely I'll use it only once (for ten wires). If you can point me in the direction of a more generic tool or tell me what characteristics a tool should have (after all, I don't expect you to shop around for me) I'd greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: On that page you linked on the right it says "Hand Crimp Tool", which is expensive but the correct tool, you can try with needle nose pliers or some generic tool, but I would be the Molex one will perform best.

Comment: if you can find something that has the same connector on the wires, then you can cut off the connector with some of the wire length attached and splice the connector onto your cable

Comment: can you post a picture of the proprietary connector in the guitar?  .... is it this one? http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=picoblade&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction

Answer (score 2):

Crimping contacts to wires in a reliable manner requires the proper tools. Very small contacts like the one that you linked are particularly sensitive to damage or unreliable operation if not crimped with the manufacturers recommended tool.

There are some generic tools that are low cost but they are generally very low quality and can only make passable crimps on contacts that are much larger and more generic than the type you have shown.

Sometimes it is possible to very carefully solder the tips of the wires to the crimp end of contacts in specific test cases. But doing so leaves a connection that is extremely susceptible to breakage, solder getting in to the contact area and difficulty getting the contact into the connector housing.